# How to calculate the distance between a mini batch and a set of filters in PyTorch

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I have a mini-batch of size NxDxWxH, where N is the size of the mini-batch, D is the dimension, and W and H are the width and height respectively. Assume that I have a set of filters F, each with dimension Dx1x1. I need to calculate the pairwise distance between the mini-batch and the filters. The size of the output should be NxFxWxH.

```
      input:   NxDxWxH
      filters: FxDx1x1
      output:  NxFxWxH
```

Lets assume a is a vector of size D extracted at the location (x,y) of the input and f is filter of size Dx1x1. Each value in the output should be `\sum_{d=1}^D (x_d - f_c)^2`.

In other words, instead of convolution I am trying to find the pair-wise L2 distances.

How can I do this in pytorch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by expanding the input and filters for proper automatic shape casting.

```
# Assuming that input.size() is (N, D, W, H) and filters.size() is (F, D, 1, 1)
input.unsqueeze_(1)
filters.unsqueeze_(0)
output = torch.sum((input - filters)**2, dim=2)
```

Comment: When I try to access my convolutional layers weight using "w = self.conv2.weight.unsqueeze_(0)" I am getting the following error: "a leaf Variable that requires grad has been used in an in-place operation". If I unsqueeze will autogradients will work?

Comment: No, you should not use inplace versions of the function with Variables. You can simply use `unsqueeze` (without the `_`) and store those values in new variables.

Comment: Thanks. But I am getting out or memory error. Is there any memory efficient way to do this? My tensors are torch.Size([1, 128, 128, 1, 1])
torch.Size([128, 128, 128, 16, 16]) after unsqueezing.

Comment: I do not think you can get any more efficient than this. Infact this should not alone produce memory error on a decent enough GPU. But, if you want to reduce its memory usage, the best you can do is to serialize the computation per input batch using loops. That way you won't incur memory cost for the `D` dimension but that won't be any considerable reduction given the cost of graph creation and runtime. It is probable that some other component of your model is the memory bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks I will try to serialize.